# How can I modify variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable

I have the following variable:

```
col=1,3,4,
```

Is there anyway to select the numbers within the variable: (i.e. 1 3 4 and work with them?

Such as choosing the "1", "3", or  "4" column from a `.txt` file?

Comment: I have no idea what this question means. Please post your script, describe how it works now, and what you want to change.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there anyway to select the numbers of the variable: 1 3 4 and work with them?

```
$ col=1,3,4,; IFS=","; for i in $col; do echo "i= $i"; done
i= 1
i= 3
i= 4
```

But changing the Internal Field Separator (`IFS`) can be dangerous as its a system-wide variable and many applications rely on its default value. So it's recommended that you save and restore its original value every time you need to modify it.

```
$ col=1,3,4,
$ OLDIFS=$IFS
$ IFS=","; for i in $col; do echo "i= $i"; done
i= 1
i= 3
i= 4

$ IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use some `read` magic:

```
i=1,2,3,; echo $i | { IFS=","; read a b c; echo "$a|$b|$c"; }
i=1,2,3,; read a b c <<<$(IFS=","; echo $i); echo "$a|$b|$c"
i=1,2,3,; echo $i | { while read -d\, j; do echo $j; done; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the list as an array variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
col=1,3,4
declare -a colArray=($(echo $col | tr ',' ' '))
echo ${#colArray[@]} # number of elements in the array
echo ${colArray[0]}  # first element of the array
for i in $(seq 0 $((${#colArray[@]}-1)))  # loop through the array
do
    echo ${colArray[$i]}
done
```

Looping through can be done several different ways, I just picked one.  Much safer than messing around with IFS.

Answer (score 1):

Given `$col` is just a string you only need to convert those commas (`,`) to spaces, and you'll be able to use a loop such as `for` to iterate through them.

Here are 2 methods, using `sed` in the 1st, and the search and replace facility in Bash:

```
$ echo $col | sed 's/,/ /g'
1 3 4 

$ echo ${col//,/ }
1 3 4
```

If you selectively want one of the values you could use `cut` instead:

```
$ echo $col | cut -d"," -f1
1
$ echo $col | cut -d"," -f2
3
$ echo $col | cut -d"," -f3
4
```

#### Example

Here's the `sed` solution with a loop, as we "walk" through the values of `$col`.

```
$ for i in $(echo $col | sed 's/,/ /g'); do echo $i; done
1
3
4
```

Each time through the loop we could be putting the `$col` values into another variable or doing whatever it is you need to do as you iterate through `$col`.

```
for  i in $(echo $col | sed 's/,/ /g'); do
  ...use $i in here...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Internal Field Separator (IFS) can be dangerous as it,s a system-wide variable and many applications rely on its default value. So it's recommended that you save and restore its original value every time you need to modify it.

Example using a previous suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash
col=1,3,4,
OLD_IFS=$IFS 
IFS=","
for i in $col; do 
  echo "i= $i"
done
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Comment: What you say is correct: changing `IFS` and not setting it back can be dangerous. But why bother restoring `IFS` when you can run the sequence of commands in a subshell? E.g. `( IFS=","; for i in ... done )`. Then the current `IFS` will not be changed.

Comment: If the "example using previous suggestion" is the whole thing then that will if executed open up a subsheell too, making changing back `IFS` redundant as the variable is not exported onto its parent.

Comment: Yes, it's true that in this simplistic example, it's redundant to worry about restoring IFS. However, in a longer and more complex script you can certainly run into weird and hard to debug issues if you are not careful when modifying the IFS. So, I consider a rule of thumb to always preserve the original IFS value as a safe-guard anyway. Ideally, I would search for alternative methods that wouldn't involve modifying the IFS at all.